# How to capture One Signal push notification objects on windows?

Tags: push-notification, angular6, onesignal

I have added the script and One Signal SDKs to my Angular 6 app. I am able to receive push notifications in the app on Chrome (Windows). How to capture the additional data fields that are sent in the one signal push notification?

This is the script that I have added in the index.html file.

```
<script>
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.init({
            appId: "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in the event you will find the additional data fields

```
 var OneSignal = window['OneSignal'] || [];
 OneSignal.push(function() {
   //This event can be listened to via the on() or once() listener
   OneSignal.on('notificationDisplay', function(event)  {  
   console.warn('OneSignal notification displayed,data:', event);
   });
 });
```